# Retrieve ALL Github issues of a specific Project using the GraphQL API

Tags: github, github-graphql, github-api-v4

I've been trying to retrieve all GitHub issues of a specific project using their GraphQL API.
The problem that i have is that i need to specify in the items a `first` or `last` param it doesn't work. Although by specifying one of these params i get only a partition of the issues.

I thought that i could get the first 100, then use pagination and get the other 100 etc until the response is an empty list. From what i read, i cannot find a parameter in the `items` that defines a page.

What are your thoughts on this? Is there a workaround?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This query seems to work fine and gives `page info` under `items`,

```
query{
  organization(login: "microsoft") {
    projectV2(number: 559) {
      title
      items(first: 100) {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output,

```
{
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "projectV2": {
        "title": "Azure TRE - Engineering",
        "items": {
          "pageInfo": {
            "endCursor": "Njc",
            "hasNextPage": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tested the query using,

> [GitHub Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using GitHub [gh CLI](https://cli.github.com/).

`gh issue` commands have a list option and you could use `--json` flag to select a field, like:

```
gh issue list -s all -L 500 --json title --json number --json body --json comments --json author --json closed --json closedAt --json createdAt --json id --json labels --json state --json updatedAt > issues.json
bck-i-search: --js
```

The `-L 500` could be updated to increase the number of the issues and you could save the result in a `.json` file using `> issue.json` at the end of the script:

```
gh issue list -s all -L 3500 --json title --json number --json body --json comments --json author --json closed --json closedAt --json createdAt --json id --json labels --json state --json updatedAt > issues.json
bck-i-search: --js > issues.json
```

The available fields to use with the `--json` flag are:

- assignees
- author
- body
- closed
- closedAt
- comments
- createdAt
- id
- labels
- milestone
- number
- projectCards
- reactionGroups
- state
- title
- updatedAt
- url